# Error: expected identifier before '(' token appearing 13 times

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I know this is not exactly a "question" but I have tried my best to present neatly as possible.

I keep getting this error:

Error: expected identifier before '(' token for 13 times.

I've checked if I

1) have extra/missing any parenthesis

2) added/missed any semicolons

3) Missed any header files

```
In function 'goToFloor':

Line 86|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 88|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 90|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 94|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 99|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 101|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 102|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 106|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 107|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 112|error: expected identifier before '(' token

In function 'printElevators':

Line 122|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 123|error: expected identifier before '(' token
Line 124|error: expected identifier before '(' token

||=== Build failed: 13 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

---

I've included the whole code and not just where the errors happened as I have a feeling the errors are not in them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CAPACITY 15
#define MAX_LEN 21


typedef struct elevator_t
{
    int floor;
    int passenger;
    int usage;

} elevator_t;

//main function
void setupElevators(elevator_t [], int);
void readSequences(char [][MAX_LEN], int);
void runElevators(elevator_t * elevators, char (* sequences)[MAX_LEN], int size);
void printElevators(elevator_t [], int size);
int mostUsedElevator(elevator_t [], int);

//sub functions
void goToFloor(elevator_t *elevator, int floor);//local to runElevator


int main(void)
{
    int size;
    elevator_t * elevators;
    char (* sequences)[MAX_LEN];

    printf("Enter number of elevators( 1 - 20 )PS I'm not validating: ");
    scanf(" %d", &size);

    setupElevators(elevators, size);
    readSequences(sequences, size);

    runElevators(elevators, sequences, size);

    printElevators(elevators, size);
    //printf("Most used elevator: %d\n", mostUsedElevator(elevators, size));

    return 0;
}


void dynamAlloc(elevator_t ** elevators,char (** sequences)[MAX_LEN],int size)
{
  *elevators=calloc( size, sizeof(**elevators) ); //wanna intialize everyting to 0
  *sequences=calloc( size, sizeof(**sequences) );
}


// Read in the sequences of floors the elevators go to.
void readSequences(char (*sequences)[MAX_LEN], int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter sequence for elevator %d: ", i+1);
        scanf(" %s", sequences[i]);
    }
}

void runElevators(elevator_t * elevators, char (* sequences)[MAX_LEN], int size)
{
    int floor_number=0,elevator_number;

    for(elevator_number=0; elevator_number<=size-1; elevator_number++)
    {
        while(sequences[elevator_number][floor_number]!='\0')
        {
            goToFloor(&elevators[elevator_number],floor_number);
            floor_number++;
        }
    }
}

void goToFloor(elevator_t *elevator, int floor)
{
    if( floor>  (*elevator).(floor)  )//going up, passengers are entering
    {
        if( (*elevator).(passenger) + floor >CAPACITY ) // cant take more than 15
        {
            (*elevator).(passenger)=CAPACITY;
        }
        else //<=15
        {
           (*elevator).(passenger)+= floor;
        }
    }
    else//going down, passengers are exiting
    {
       if( floor<=(*elevator).(passenger)) //whichever amount is lower will be the amount 
       {
           (*elevator).(passenger)-=floor;
           (*elevator).(usage)+=floor;
       }
       else
       {
           (*elevator).(usage)+=(*elevator).(passenger);
           (*elevator).(passenger)-=(*elevator).(passenger);

       }
    }

    (*elevator).(floor)=floor;//update current floor lift is at
}

void printElevators(elevator_t elevators[], int size)
{
    int elevator_number;

    for(elevator_number=0;elevator_number<=size-1;elevator_number++)
    {
        printf("Elevator %d:\n",elevator_number+1);
        printf("Floor: \n",( elevators[elevator_number] ).(floor));
        printf("Number of passengers: \n",( elevators[elevator_number] ).(passenger) );
        printf("Usage: \n", ( elevators[elevator_number] ).(usage) );
}
    }


int mostUsedElevator(elevator_t elevators[], int size)
{
    // Incomplete
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `(*elevator).(floor)` isn't valid C syntax. You can use `(*elevator).floor` or `elevator->floor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors are frequently around constructs like this:

```
(*elevator).(passenger)=CAPACITY;

prog.c:88:25: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
             (*elevator).(passenger)=CAPACITY;
                         ^---------Error Here
```

That is a very strange and obtuse, and incorrect, way to use a structure.

What follows the `.` ***must*** be a field of a structure.
Trying to use `(`parens`)` means that it is an expression to be evaluated.
But an expression is not valid here, it must be a field-name.

This should be:

```
elevator->passenger = CAPACITY;
```

Comment: Why is there a difference between  (*elevator).(passenger) and (*elevator).passenger? Shoulndn't the parenthesis not change anything?